# How can update Parse AppVersion

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am sending pushes from Parse website. I have different versions of my iOS app. But  appVersion is 1 for all iOS users. 
How can i update appVersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appVersion used by Parse (and a lot of other services, like Crashlytics) is actually not the version of the app, but the build number. So you need to align your build number with your version. What I do for my apps is that my build number is composed of the current version number + the "real" build number. For the version `4.2` of my app, my build number was `4.2.0.1`.

You can Change the build number in xcode. The field is located right under the `version` field, in the `General` tab.